# Serve a custom 404 page generated by PHP

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, http-status-code-404

Here is how my php-fpm config is:

```
location @site {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 /404;
}
```

Because `fastcgi_intercept_errors` is enabled, when my PHP router returns a 404, Nginx will redirect to `/404`. **Good**.

But since `/404` is generated by my PHP application, and my PHP application correctly sets a `404` response code, then Nginx will try to handle the error again! (which obviously ends in a loop)

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx is doing this because you told it to.

```
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

This means that [nginx will not serve error responses generated by PHP,](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_intercept_errors) but have nginx handle them instead. Thus you get into your endless loop.

To resolve the problem, remove this directive (it defaults to `off`) or set it explicity to `off`.

Comment: If I did, I would have to handle myself 404 errors in my application (to show the `/404` page). IMO that's not a perfect solution (because I need to implement that at the PHP level, instead of Nginx), but I couldn't find any other so that's what I did.

Comment: Any web application that utilizes the front controller pattern must provide a 404 handler, because in order to make this pattern work, the web server must send all requests which don't match a static resource to the web application.

Comment: True but I was hoping for something like this: Nginx (not a static resource) => PHP app (not a route, return empty 404) => Nginx (404, intercept error) => redirect to `/404` => PHP app (generates the 404 page).

Comment: The PHP app should just send the 404 page the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Make your script that generates the error page to return HTTP 200 (i.e. a proper page) and it should work right away.

nginx will retrieve the body of /404 and will update the response status to be 404.

P.S. as a bonus you may want to define an explicit location (e.g. location = /404 ) and turn fastcgi_cache on there so your PHP backend is not queried each time you need your error page displayed.